# Safe alternatives to painkillers/nsaid?

Tags: treatment-options, headache, nsaids-pain-meds, analgesics

So recently I have started a new job, and a common thing in the last few weeks is I have been getting headaches occasionally, that will last the rest of the day.

The issue is, I workout right after work, and from what I have read, NSAIDs (Ibuprofen, Tylenol, Aspirin, Naproxen) can worsen workouts and prevent protein synthesis in the muscles. And that they are not "safe" on the body.

Im trying to Google what would be the safest (if being least damaging) painkiller for headaches, but all I find is clickbait articles talking about what is bad for the body.

Any tips/help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Paracetamol is not on the NSAID list, use that? Treat the cause, not the symptom, if work is causing headaches then determine what is causing it: lack of sleep/stress/eye-strain/fatigue etc.

Comment: http://stm.sciencemag.org/content/6/218/218ra5

Answer (score 1):

I am really happy that I found Krill oil. It's an omega 3,6,9 oil made from krill. (a sea creature similar to shrimp but much smaller). It makes this choice the strongest choice in benefits of any fish oil, but no yucky taste if you burp. I can't take NSAIDS anymore, but I found that after a few days of taking krill oil, it works as an anti-inflammatory pain killer for me when I take an extra one when pain comes on. No side effects, no drug interactions. 
Source:  [National Institute of Health](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17353582)

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)